# Including wp-blog-header.php from functions.php remote call?

Tags: theme-development

I have a script that's called from my functions.php file (via an ajax .get) that needs to have access to WP's get_option() method in order to retrieve some values it needs to process.

However, although the file works great in the majority of sites where it resides, on just a few installations, I'm having problems with the script operating (chrome's javascript console reports a 404 (not found) on color.php.

```
//jQuery calls the file color.php

$('#my_theme_switcher').change
(
    function() 
    {
        $.get
        ('<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/color.php', 
        {theme: 'test', spot: '1'}, 
        function(data)
            {
                doColor('#theme_header_color', data);
            }
        );
    }
);


Here is the file color.php

<?php
require_once('../../../wp-blog-header.php');
echo 'all good';
?>
```

In this case, I never get the echo since it appears that the require statement has failed to load the wp-blog-header.php

Is there an alternative way of including the header file in order to be able to call get_option()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't need to make direct calls to your theme files - use the AJAX API, and make all requests to `admin-ajax.php` (that way, WordPress'll be loaded for you, and you won't need to assume the file hierarchy in order to load it manually).

```
$.get(
    '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ?>',

    {
        "color_theme" : "test",
        "color_spot" : "1",
        "action" : "change_color"
    },

    function( data ) {
        doColor( '#theme_header_color', data );
    }
);
```

And in `functions.php`;

```
function __do_color_ajax()
{
    $theme = $_GET['color_theme'];
    $spot = $_GET['color_spot'];

    // do something

    die( 'AJAX output' );
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_change_color', '__do_color_ajax' );
```

See how the suffix of the hook, `wp_ajax_nopriv_change_color`, matches the action variable in the AJAX request? [See this SE answer for more info](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15964/how-to-make-ajax-call-in-wordpress-in-right-way/15984#15984).

Note I've also prefixed the other AJAX request variables, as you should [namespace custom `$_GET` and `$_POST` variables](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12169/why-is-posting-to-my-wp-page-template-producing-a-404/12173#12173) in the same way you do PHP variables and functions.

Also check out the [codex on the AJAX API](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

Comment: Thanks for that TDM, however, I've got some code inside of color.php that I want to execute and pass the result back to ajax. Can you tell me how to include my color.php file in your example?

Comment: Instead of including the file, you would make a callback function and attach it to the appropriate action hook, as mentioned in the Codex article.

Comment: BTW, if you *really* want to to it more like your original approach, I can tell you how, but I don't recommend it.

Comment: Thanks, but since I'm using jQuery, I'm having a tough go of translating the pure Ajax example to my script. My first thought, using what I already have, was to pass the ABSPATH constant over to the color.php, but I'm having pathing issues with the slashes.

Comment: Just trying to determine how to pass the PHP callback function name in the jQuery. Would it be the value of the "action" argument? action = 'myPHPfunction'; ?

Comment: @Scott B check my revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the way you make the include in your color.php to:

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'./wp-blog-header.php');
```

Comment: This still makes assumptions about the filesystem. Why reinvent the wheel, when WordPress has already given you a Porsche 911 Turbo? ;)